# Exit application only when clicking 'X' button with 'Shift' key hold?

Tags: wpf, exit-code

Normally clicking 'X' button at the top right corner will exit the application. I want my window form application to exit only when holding the 'Shift' click. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a handler to the `Closing` event and cancel if the appropriate modifiers are set by checking `Keyboard.Modifiers` and cancel as necessary.  You may need to add logic to check if the mouse clicked the close button if you wish.

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift) return; //exit if shift pressed

    //cancel by default
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```